# Can't __declspec(dllexport) a class standalone

Tags: c++, windows, class, dllexport

Suppose I have a `myarray.h` file:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include "pch.h"

namespace marr {

    template <typename T>
    class __declspec(dllexport) myarray {
    private:
        T* arr = NULL;
        int capacity;
    public:
        myarray(int initialCapacity = 0) {
            if (initialCapacity != 0)
                this->arr = new T[initialCapacity];
            this->capacity = initialCapacity;
        }
        T& operator[](int index) {
            if (this->capacity <= index)
                this->growCapacityTo(index + 1);
            return this->arr[index];
        }
        ~myarray() {
            delete[] this->arr;
        }
    private:
        void growCapacityTo(int count) {
            T* newarr = new T[count];
            for (int i = 0; i < this->capacity; ++i)
                newarr[i] = this->arr[i];
            this->capacity = count;
            delete[] this->arr;
            this->arr = newarr;
        }
    };

}
```

And `myarray.cpp`:

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include "myarray.h"
// Nothing
```

Buildingthe above in Visual Studio does not create a `.lib` file.

Removing the template doesn't change this fact:

```cpp
class __declspec(dllexport) myarray {
    private:
        int* arr = NULL;
        int capacity;
    public:
        myarray(int initialCapacity = 0) {
            if (initialCapacity != 0)
                this->arr = new int[initialCapacity];
            this->capacity = initialCapacity;
        }
        int& operator[](int index) {
            if (this->capacity <= index)
                this->growCapacityTo(index + 1);
            return this->arr[index];
        }
        ~myarray() {
            delete[] this->arr;
        }
    private:
        void growCapacityTo(int count) {
            int* newarr = new int[count];
            for (int i = 0; i < this->capacity; ++i)
                newarr[i] = this->arr[i];
            this->capacity = count;
            delete[] this->arr;
            this->arr = newarr;
        }
    };

}
```

Adding a random function to the header file, does result in the `.lib` file being created, for example:

```cpp
__declspec(dllexport) int test() {
    return 0;
}
```

Is this the correct and expected behaviour?

Comment: You don't export templates in a dll. You include the headers.

Comment: You can export specializations but not the template itself (after all, a template by itself isn't code that could be linked against)

Comment: without the `template <typename T>` it still doesn't work

Comment: You will need to have a `.cpp` file in the project that includes the header. Also normally you use a macro that switches between `__declspec(dllexport)` and `__declspec(dllimport)` depending on if you are building or using the dll.

Comment: In addition to comments, you export / import in case of DLL (dynamic library), not in case of LIB (static library).

Comment: You probably should start with this tutorial from Microsoft: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=msvc-160](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=msvc-160)

Comment: First of all, I did have a macro, but just to check if that was the problem, I removed it temprarily, not to meantion that it doesn't matter at the moment. Secondly, I did follow the "Create and use your own Dynamic Link Library" Microsoft docs: "In the Additional Dependencies dialog, add MathLibrary.lib to the list in the top edit control", so I do need the class exported in the `.lib` file